# How to always hide a div when the submit button is first clicked?

Tags: javascript

I want to permanently hide the `<div id="hideOnSubmit">` after pressing the submit button

I’m creating a multi-step form, what I mean when the user skips the first step, the div disappears

```html
<div class="frm_submit">
[if back_button]<button type="submit" name="frm_prev_page" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" class="frm_prev_page" [back_hook]>[back_label]</button>[/if back_button]
<button class="frm_button_submit" type="submit" id="toggle" [button_action]>[button_label]</button>
<div class="frm_button_submitt" id="hideOnSubmit">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" value="true" tabindex="4"><i class="a-icon a-icon-checkbox"></i><span class="a-label a-checkbox-label">
          Keep me signed in.
          <span class="a-declarative" data-action="a-popover" data-a-popover="{&quot;activate&quot;:&quot;onclick&quot;,&quot;header&quot;:&quot;\&quot;Keep Me Signed In\&quot; Checkbox&quot;,&quot;inlineContent&quot;:&quot;\u003cp>Choosing \&quot;Keep me signed in\&quot; reduces the number of times you're asked to Sign-In on this device.\u003c\/p>\n\u003cp>To keep your account secure, use this option only on your personal devices.\u003c\/p>&quot;}">
            <a id="remember_me_learn_more_link" href="javascript:void(0)" class="a-popover-trigger a-declarative">
              Details
            <i class="a-icon a-icon-popover"></i></a>
          </span>
</span></label>
</div>
[if save_draft]<a href="#" tabindex="0" class="frm_save_draft" [draft_hook]>[draft_label]</a>[/if save_draft]
</div>
```

```js
const elementToHide = document.querySelector("#hideOnSubmit");

document.querySelector("#toggle").addEventListener("click", () => {
  elementToHide.style.display = "none";
});
```

[It disappears in the first step, but I want it to disappear in the next steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSgSg.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution. Just use a counter.

```js
const element = document.getElementById("hide");
let clickCount = 0;

element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if(clickCount > 0) return element.style.display = "none";
  
  console.log("Clicked")
  clickCount++;
});
```

```html
<div id="hide">Hide me on the second Click</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand very well, please can you give a full solution?

Comment: @AbderrahmaneAbidi, you said you want to make it invisible on the next step. I assume that means on the second click. So we need to know how many times we've clicked that element. That's why we are using a clickCounter variable to keep track of how many times we've clicked the element. At first the clickCounter = 0. When we click it for the first time we check if the clickCounter is greater than zero. If it's not then we increment the counter. By the way clickCounter++ is the same as clickCounter = clickCounter + 1;  So after the first click the clickCounter becomes 1 and we hide it.

Answer (score 0):

From the error it seems like your button doesn't exist. Do you destroy the button when you press Sign-In? Then maybe try something like this:

```
 document.querySelector("#toggle").addEventListener("click", () => {
     if (!document.querySelector("#toggle")) {
         elementToHide.style.display = "none";
     }
 });
```

To hide your element when the button changes.

Comment: I don't understand very well, please can you give a full solution?